# Check errors when calling http.ResponseWriter.Write()

Tags: http, go, error-handling, server

Say I have this http handler:

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := GetSomeData()
    _, err := w.Write(data)
}
```

Should I check the error returned by `w.Write`? Examples I've seen just ignore it and do nothing. Also, functions like `http.Error()` do not return an error to be handled.

Comment: "Should I check the error returned ..." The answer depends on your requirements. How do you intend to react if an error occurs? If you check for an error and on error all you do is "No idea what to do now... let's log to /dev/null and call it handled." then you could ignore the error es well. General advice can be given on general problems. Your's isn't general.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's up to you. My advice is that unless the documentation of some method / function explicitly states that it never returns a non-`nil` error (such as [`bytes.Buffer.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Write)), always check the error and the least you can do is log it, so if an error occurs, it will leave some mark which you can investigate should it become a problem later.

This is also true for writing to [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).

You might think `ResponseWriter.Write()` may only return errors if sending the data fails (e.g. connection closed), but that is not true. The concrete type that implements `http.ResponseWriter` is the unexported `http.response` type, and if you check the unexported `response.write()` method, you'll see it might return a non-`nil` error for a bunch of other reasons.

**Reasons why `ResponseWriter.Write()` may return a non-`nil` error:**

- If the connection was hijacked (see [`http.Hijacker`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker)): `http.ErrHijacked`
- If content length was specified, and you attempt to write more than that: `http.ErrContentLength`
- If the HTTP method and / or HTTP status does not allow a response body at all, and you attempt to write more than 0 bytes: `http.ErrBodyNotAllowed`
- If writing data to the actual connection fails.

Even if you can't do anything with the error, logging it may be of great help debugging the error later on. E.g. you (or someone else in the handler chain) hijacked the connection, and you attempt to write to it later; you get an error (`http.ErrHijacked`), logging it will reveal the cause immediately.

#### Tip for "easy" logging errors

If you can't do anything with the occasional error and it's not a "showstopper", you may create and use a simple function that does the check and logging, something like this:

```
func logerr(n int, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Write failed: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
logerr(w.Write(data))
```

#### Tip for "auto-logging" errors

If you don't even want to use the `logerr()` function all the time, you may create a wrapper for `http.ResponseWriter` which does this "automatically":

```
type LogWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
}

func (w LogWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = w.ResponseWriter.Write(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Write failed: %v", err)
    }
    return
}
```

Using it:

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w = LogWriter{w}
    w.Write([]byte("hi"))
}
```

Using `LogWriter` as a wrapper around `http.ResponseWriter`, should writes to the original `http.ResponseWriter` fail, it will be logged automatically.

This also has the great benefit of not expecting a logger function to be called, so you can pass a value of your `LogWriter` "down" the chain, and everyone who attempts to write to it will be monitored and logged, they don't have to worry or even know about this.

But care must be taken when passing `LogWriter` down the chain, as there's also a downside to this: a value of `LogWriter` will not implement other interfaces the original `http.ResponseWriter` might also do, e.g. `http.Hijacker` or [`http.Pusher`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Pusher).

Here's an example on the [**Go Playground**](https://play.golang.org/p/VtPmgtbhP5) that shows this in action, and also shows that `LogWriter` will not implement other interfaces; and also shows a way (using 2 "nested" type assertions) how to still get out what we want from `LogWriter` (an `http.Pusher` in the example).

Comment: Based on what I've seen in a few posts the "tip for auto-logging errors" option could be ditched. An explanation can be found here: https://blog.merovius.de/2017/07/30/the-trouble-with-optional-interfaces.html

Comment: Although it is already mentioned in the answer "But care must be taken when passing ...." I just wanted to drop the link here for those who want to know what exactly issue is so the answer is +1.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add to @icza solution. You don't need to create logging structure, you can use simple function:

```golang
func logWrite(write func([]byte) (int, error), body []byte) {
    _, err := write(body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Write failed: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Take a look on that approach based on the @icza code: https://play.golang.org/p/PAetVixCgv4